# Error: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line **: did not find expected key

Tags: go, kubernetes, charts, cloud, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install a Helm chart, but I'm receiving errors from an annotation

```
  annotations: {}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
```

```
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line **: did not find expected key
```

```
code fast with www.microapi.io
```

Comment: you have an empty {} and then you have annotations , Also are you writing the chart yourself or pulling from somewhere ?

Comment: Hello, could you tell if the comment made by Tarun Khosla solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Remove {}

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
```